# Cassette.AspNet on a Azure Cloud Service - how will it scale?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-roles, cassette

I searched and couldn't find any references to my question:
is it safe to use Cassette.AspNet when hosting a web application in Azure Cloud Services?

Currently we are using it and everything works fine, but we have only one instance.
What should we expect when we scale?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't see a reason why this shouldn't scale.
But we moved away from Cassette to the official Microsoft Optimization Framework.

http://remy.supertext.ch/2013/02/extending-the-asp-net-optimization-framework/

It's just often easier to work with MS stuff.

Comment: Isn't Cassette keeping the minified and combined files in memory? And if we have two instances, don't they have separate memories?
I'm sorry, but I am new in Azure development and Cloud services, so probably something is not clear enough to me :)

Thanks!

Comment: Right, that is the case as far as I know. But it's similar with Microsofts Solution. I think it will be difficult to find an optimization framework, that would store that central.
But the overhead of storing a few scripts in memory is minimal I think.